# Hibernate - Return collection of entities by ID knowing only the class

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

How do I load a collection of entities of a given class, with only a single trip to the database, e.g.:

```
 public Collection<Object> getEntities(Class<?> entityClass,Collection<Serializable> listOfIDs);
```

I know that if I were only wanting to fetch a single entity, I could use:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Class,Serializable);
```

but there doesn't seem to be a matching option for a collection of Serializables.

Note that as I only know the class, I don't know the name of the Identity Column, so simple HQL / Criteria API is not an option, without first discovering the ID column.

Comment: You may not know the id _column_ name, but what about the id _property_ name?  You always provide property names to HQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate does not provide support for that out of the box. But you can achieve this in HQL with the help of the special `id` property:

> #### [14.5. Referring to identifier property](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-identifier-property)
>
> There are 2 ways to refer to an
>   entity's identifier property:
>
> - The special property (lowercase) `id` may be used to reference the
>     identifier property of an entity
>     provided that the entity does not
>     define a non-identifier property named
>     `id`.
> - If the entity defines a named identifier property, you can use that
>     property name.

So you could do something like this:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from " + clazz.getName() + " where id IN :idList")
```

Answer (score 2):

As you suggested in your question, you can discover the ID property name and then use it to build your criteria. Use `SessionFactory` to obtain `ClassMetadata` and ask it for the `IdentifierPropertyName`. Here is a small snippet that does what you need.

```
public <T> List<T> listByIds(Class<T> entityType, Collection<? extends Serializable> ids) {
        Session session = getSession();
        String idPropertyName = session.getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(entityType).getIdentifierPropertyName();

        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(entityType)
                .add(Restrictions.in(idPropertyName, ids));

        return criteria.list();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just execute an `HQL` query - "`from MyEntity where ...`", which will return a list of the entities? Just build the `where` clause manually. Another option is to use [Criteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) API.

Edit: Use "`where id = ...`". Hibernate will automatically find the `id` column for you, no matter how it is named.

Comment: You can't use either of these options (that I can see) without knowing the name of the identity column.

Comment: Ah OK, I get what you want to do now:)

Comment: You can use "id" in the where clause and Hibernate will automatically find the identity column.

Comment: Why should I "build the where clause manually" when I have Criteria API?
maraswrona and Pascal Thivent provided better answers.

Comment: Well, I have written that `Another option is to use Criteria API.`